# Are there pieces that require retuning an instrument mid-performance?

Tags: technique, tuning

Are there any musical pieces that call for the musician to detune/retune the instrument, not in advance like a scordatura, but mid-performance?

I think it would be a neat avant-garde concept—for example, temporarily adjusting the peg of a violin's G string to play F#3 then adjusting it back, etc. I'd imagine it would be challenging but not impossible, and I'm curious to know if such pieces exist.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're asking about instruments in general (as the title suggests) or the violin specifically (as the tags suggest).

Comment: There's a lot in banjo repertoire that uses Keith tuners, which have tuned stops that allow the quick switch between tunings. "Flint Hill Special" is one particular piece that uses this technique.

Comment: It's not that uncommon. Richard Strauss frequently demands notes below the lowest open string, which strictly speaking would require re-tuning in performances (Salome, Elektra, Alpensinfonie...) In practice, however, these are often just omitted.

Comment: Regarding retuning and tuning back during performance, some guitarists (at least one guitarist, anyway) do this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY7GnAq6Znw

Comment: Slightly facetiously: most pedal-steel pieces require retuning the instrument mid-note. Kind of

Comment: In the 1980s the guitarist Alex de Grassi was invited to perform at Virginia Tech, and I saw him in live performance in an intimate space. At one point in one of his pieces, he abruptly stopped and explained, "sorry, at this point I need to switch guitars; the rest requires a different tuning." Don't recall which piece.

Comment: @Aaron violin immediately came to mind since that's what I'm familiar with, but I never considered the other neat examples that people pointed out below. I've removed the tag.

Comment: My born-to-nitpick mind read this question and immediately jumped: "define retuning!" If you squint at it a little, every time a harpist presses a pedal they retune their strings (to a different key) :P

Comment: Impressive performance by Ed Sheeran : https://youtu.be/nUx9tNzpbbs?t=15 He moves the capo and retunes the guitar at https://youtu.be/nUx9tNzpbbs?t=60

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scordatura) has an long list of scordatura examples arranged by instrument.

Comment: This is becoming more common in guitar as well, with Alexandr Misko (e.g. in Careless Whisper https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzgTMh21zhI&ab_channel=AlexandrMisko), Jon Gomm (e.g. in Passionflower https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY7GnAq6Znw&ab_channel=JonGomm) and Mike Dawes all making use of this technique (most use equipment to aid in the tuning; Jon Gomm doesn't). Charles Berthoud also does it on bass (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeX0Gd8zyLY&ab_channel=CharlesBerthoud).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In relation to the violin (or other string instrument) the specific technique described — using the tuning peg to detune and retune a pitch — is called **peg scordatura** (also *peg glissando* and *glissando scordatura*).

A very clear example of this occurs in Alfred Schnittke's *Stille Nacht* (1978) for violin and piano. At the end of the piece, the violin detunes and retunes the open G string down to D and back to G again, creating an eerie glissando. Note also the very end of the piece, in which the tuning peg is used to create a vibrato/trill effect. The below recording is timed to the peg scordatura.

---

In the comments below, it's pointed out that for technical reasons, peg scordatura will only be found on the final note of a piece.

Here are some counterexamples:

**György Kurtág's *Kafka Fragmente* (Op. 24)** includes peg glissandi: for example, the section from 27:37 – 28:58 in the below recording.

**Stavros Choplaros's "Sonata da Chiesa" (2015)** uses peg scordatura throughout. The below images are just two examples from the score, which is included in his [doctoral dissertation](https://kclpure.kcl.ac.uk/portal/files/127987083/2020_Choplaros_Stavros_1412063_ethesis.pdf) from King's College (PDF pages 139–150).

[image: Choplaros, "Sonata da Chiesa" (2015), m. 5, violin peg gliss.]

[image: Choplaros, "Sonata da Chiesa" (2015), m. 93–95, violin peg gliss.]

In **Karl Gerber's "Three Formulae on One String"**, a computer-controlled violin employs peg scordatura. In the below Vimeo recording, the technique is first used beginning at 1:14.

[Gerber, "Three Formulae on One String"](https://vimeo.com/469262982)

Comment: It's maybe worth adding that you're only going to see this on the very last note of a piece.  Without geared tuners or tuning levers like a harp has, it's impossible to change tuning accurately - friction pegs simply don't allow it, and the fine-tuners on a violin bridge can't be changed fast enough.  Even with geared tuners on a guitar, it's hard to do.  Violins do exist with geared tuners, but they're rare and are usually custom-made.

Comment: @Graham I think that's over-broad. For example, in "[Evolution and Notation of Glissando in String Music](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/24045922.pdf)", John L. Snyder points to an example in Ligeti's _Apparitions_ that is mid-piece. (Listening to a recording, it's clearly not at the end, but I can't find for certain where it does occur.)

Comment: Everyone's examples were great but this is closest to what I was thinking of. Using peg scordatura as an eerie vibrato was just too cool. It would have been better if it happened mid-piece but oh well.

Comment: link is dead/unavailable.

Comment: @Graham FYI, I added some examples of peg scordatura occurring in the middle of the pieces.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks - interesting! I guess I've overstated the case at "impossible" when it should just say "seriously difficult". :) That said, I'd be worried about tuning stability for the rest of the piece with friction pegs. A modified instrument with guitar tuners instead of friction pegs (or motorized as per your last example) would make that more reliable. Although *that* said, if the tuning is only a little out and is stable then you certainly can accommodate that with your fingers.

Answer (score 26):

Lots of classical music require retuning of timpani (or purchasing a larger drum set). Von Biber's Rosary Sonatas require retuning a violin between each section.

Comment: more modern timpani repertoire may require so many retunings that a larger drum set would be impractical

Comment: @PeterSmith for example, Appalachian Spring has a nearly complete diatonic scale if I recall correctly.  It's not practical to have six or seven drums within reach.

Comment: @phoog - I thought the third most common number of timpani in an ensemble after 0 and 4 was 8.

Comment: @Dekkadeci played by two players, I expect.  Appalachian Spring calls for one player.

Comment: @phoog A single player could have multiple positions on-stage (with different sets of drums at each) from which they can play any song for which re-tuning a single drum (or several) would be called for. If it requires playing an a full octave in the same section, that's a different matter. Even re-arranging the various drums sounds at least as doable as re-tuning.

Comment: Can't recall the exact pieces, but in college I played at least two performances where the timpani needed to be retuned between movements. We had 4 timpani.

Comment: I've played plenty of pieces on timpani that had changes throughout the piece (as many as 40 in a single movement!).  These can be done fairly quickly with the pedals and a bit of practice.  Some timpani have gauges on them to allow you to quickly reference what the current pitches are as well.  It's also not uncommon to have a fifth drum (20, 23, 26, 29, and 32-inch drums, pitch ranging from pedal D to middle C)

Comment: @jpaugh Timpani are heavy, awkward, and can be a bit tricky to move silently depending on the quality of the wheels and flooring. I played percussion for many years, but can't imagine a situation where you'd want to rearrange timpani during a performance. If you have enough time to do that, you have more than enough time to re-tune.

Comment: @Tristan: I saw a YouTube video of a percussionist during a performance of West Side Story, and the two Timpani were used for a lot more than two pitches.

Comment: @supercat Indeed.  Also not uncommon for pit orchestras, being severely cramped for space, to only have two timpani

Comment: @jpaugh - I played Timpani for about ten years between junior high and college.  Nobody rearranges drums.  You have a set of between two and five drums, and unless you have ancient hand-crank drums, you use a springloaded pedal mechanism to change the pitch. With practice, you can accurately get to a new pitch in a fraction of a second.  Experienced timpanists have no issue playing scales around the drums.

Comment: As a reference -- here's a sample of a wind ensemble timpani part I played.  For a set of four timpani, I counted six changes on the first page alone. https://www.sheetmusicdirect.com/en-US/se/ID_No/382585/Product.aspx

Comment: The Timpani has a gauge to help with tuning. The instrument doesn't have that precise tuning so there is a little bit more margin of error, and it's not like you need to be in tune with another set of Timpani.

Answer (score 23):

In "The Rite of Spring" Stravinsky requires the celli to detune their A-strings to G-sharp for the final chord of the piece (and asks them to play a four-note chord "*non arpeggiato*"!):
[image]

Similarly at the end of Jörg Widmann's [Viola Concerto](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/what-is-the-story-of-widmann-viola-concerto) the soloist has to detune the C-string over several measures:
[image]

Comment: I wonder what fraction of performances actually obey that instruction, instead of simply omitting one of the D's and playing the G♯ on the D string. Possibly divisi-split, so some play only the high D, some the low one. (Which would also enable actually playing “non arpeggiato”!)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I just looked at a couple of videos on YouTube (LA Phil, LSO). None of the cellists touched their tuning pegs :)

Comment: This excerpt is one of my favorite bits of musical trivia! Think about what's happening dramatically at the very end of this piece, and then spell out the bass notes from bottom to top.

Comment: You can't reliably down tune a string instrument like that. In string instruments, you always tune lower then tune back up to release any hidden tension caught in the groves. The last thing you want is for the tension to release while playing and then you're just screwed.

Comment: @Nelson That's why the cellists don't seem to follow Stravinsky's instructions (see the previous comments)

Answer (score 10):

The existing answers are all good - to add something else to the mix though:

For a particularly extreme example, Michael Manring the experimental bass guitarist enjoyed the expressive possibilities of retuning mid performance so much that he had an instrument purpose built to allow him to retune quickly on the fly.

This eventually has extended to whole pieces built around dynamic retuning while using natural harmonics, as heard here:

Arguably at this point that barely even counts as "retuning", it's just become another expressive capacity of the instrument.  Still, I thought it would be relevant to the discussion for an example of pushing this idea of dynamic retuning to the limit.

He talks a bit about the progression to arriving at this point here

Comment: Oh, I see that the question was tagged "violin", sorry, I only read the title and text not the tags. If question was intended to refer only to violin pieces then my apologies.

Comment: See also g-bender modification of a guitar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OKZQSAIiyc

Comment: For those who don't want to watch the entire second video, the Zon Hyperbass includes [Hipshot Bass Xtenders](https://hipshotproducts.com/collections/bass-xtenders), which serve the same function as the banjo cam tuners mentioned in another answer.  It also has a special bridge designed for easy retuning of the entire instrument at once.

Answer (score 10):

Banjo is commonly played in several different tunings.

Some banjos are fitted with cam tuners (known as D tuners, Scruggs tuners or Keith tuners) which facilitate fast, accurate retuning between two fixed notes, and which are also used to good effect during playing.

Here's an except from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_Banjo_Company explaining the history of their invention.

- > Their inspiration for going into the banjo business was Earl Scruggs' creation of homemade cam tuners, which he developed after recording "Earl's Breakdown" in 1951. Scruggs had sought to refine the way he played this tune by finding a way to re-tune more accurately during the piece. Keith was inspired by the four banjo tunes ("Earl's Breakdown", "Foggy Mountain Chimes", "Flint Hill Special", and "Randy Lynn Rag") on the 1957 Flatt and Scruggs album Foggy Mountain Jamboree, which all used Scruggs's cam tuning machines

A couple of examples of other songs where players use this technique.

Perhaps a banjo player can weigh in on this. I'm no expert (I'm a guitarist) but I note that the sound is similar to slide guitar, and both instruments are fretted, picked and played in American (country, bluegrass) folk music.

Comment: They also make D-tuners for guitar, to allow a guitarist to quickly switch between E standard and drop D tuning.

Comment: @dissemin8or they do make them for guitar (usually fitted on the 6th string for low E/D as you say)  but they're not common and I'm not aware of them being used while playing. With banjo they're usually on the 2nd and 3rd strings and it's a common thing to use them to bend notes while playing as in the videos I linked. I played a banjo once, tried to bend it in the way I would a guitar (by pushing the string sideways across the fretboard) and it didn't work out that well. Maybe that's why they bend with the tuners.

Answer (score 8):

Unless I am mistaken, no one has mentioned the Schumann Piano Quartet where the cellist is asked to tune the C string down to a Bb at the end of the slow movement, in order to hold a long pedal point.

Answer (score 4):

There's a song in the musical *Batboy* that does this. I'm forgetting a lot of the details (esp. the name of the song), but I think it was done to shift the range of the vocal melody and/or as a phrase modulation for musical interest. It just coincidentally inconvenienced the guitar player. Most of the song could be played in standard tuning except for the middle section that needed a low Eb from the guitar.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly "retuning," but lots of orchestral music has the clarinets swap between the Bb and A axe.

If one is playing all the Bach unaccompanied cello suites, one must detune for the 5th suite (A-string tuned down to G). That doesn't really count as "mid-piece."

Now, do you count using a capo on the guitar family?   Or changing settings on an autoharp?

Comment: The Bach Cello Suite #5 is the one you're thinking of.

Comment: @Aaron I plead guilty to being a cellist and not thinking there's any other set of suites by Bach :-(

Comment: I forgive you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere there's Haydn symphony where the violins are asked to retune the G string to (I think) F and then play the open string while tuning it back up to G. But I can't remember which one and I don't have the scores or time to search IMSLP.

Walton in 'Facade' asks the cello to retune the C string to B, and then notates it as a transposing instrument. I once heard a performance where the player didn't realise that and played all the C string notes a semitone sharp - not a success. That's not exactly during a piece as it's for one of the movements only so it's more like scordatura.

Comment: This is Haydn's Symphony 60 in C ("Il distratto"), and the tuning-business happens near the start of the finale, which is the 6th (!) movement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned Nigel Tufnel's performance where he retuned the violin he was using to play his guitar with.

It's quite clear from the video that the solo really wouldn't have been the same without the retune.

Comment: Could you post a video link, or maybe an article describing the performance? Speaking for myself at least, I'm not familiar with Nigel Tufnel or his retuning bit.

Comment: @Aaron Nigel Tufnel is the guitarist in the mockumentary "This is Spinal Tap" about the (fictional) metal band of the same name. Nigel is perhaps best known for being proud of his amplifier's volume control, which goes all the way up to 11 (which makes it really loud, apparently.)

Comment: Duh! Of course I know Nigel Tufnel. Oy. Anyway, I suggest you fill out your answer a bit; otherwise, i reads more like a comment. (And who wouldn't enjoy watching that scene again?)

Comment: What amuses me to this day is that Marshall amps since that movie do actually have an 11 on the dial, in tribute.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of classical music pieces that require some occasional retuning, but if they exist I suspect they are written specifically for a particular virtuoso performer who can pull it off reliably every time.

On the other hand, some virtuoso performers do exist, who among other things take advantage of the possibilities offered by the instrument's tuning machines. One example is this:

A similarly gifted guitarist, Luca Stricagnoli, occasionally does something like that, but I couldn't promptly find an example.

And while this isn't strictly an answer to your question, but to give an idea of what some people can do, I once saw Vishwa Mohan Bhatt change a broken string in the middle of a long improvisation and then tune it up as needed, and throughout this process not a single bad note was heard... in fact, if I had not been watching him, just by listening I could have thought that the improvisation just changed to a slow mood for a minute before going back to normal.

Bottom line, retuning while playing can be a thing, but only for the top of the top of players.

Comment: I recommend reading some of the other answers, which are explicit in naming pieces/composers who use detuning/retuning in their pieces, many of which are considered standard repertoire.

Comment: Jon Gomm's song Passionflower combines a similar technique with guitar harmonics, which produces quite an unusual sound where the very clear harmonic "bends" up and down, something that it normally can't really do.